# Python inheritance - subclass logic does not get called

Tags: python, python-3.x, inheritance

In my example C1 class and C2 class both inherit from Base class.
In the Base::run(self) method I am calling self.__run1 and self.__run2 methods that are overloaded in C1 and C2.

I can't see a way to execute the C1::__run1 and C2::__run2 methods.

```
class Base(object):
    def __run1(self):
        pass

    def __run2(self):
        pass

    def run(self):
        self.__run1()
        self.__run2()


class C1(Base):
    def __run1(self):
        print("C1 run1")

class C2(Base):
    def __run2(self):
        print("C2 run2")

o1 = C1()
o2 = C2()

o1.run()
#how to make it return C1 run1?
o2.run()
#how to make it return C2 run2?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `__methods` are private. The `_methods` are hidden and protected. Use `_run1()` and `_run2()`

#### Example

```
class Base(object):
    def _run1(self): # protected
        pass

    def __run2(self): # private
        pass

    def run(self):
        self._run1()
        self.__run2()


class C1(Base):
    def _run1(self): # overrides old _run1
        print("C1 run1")

class C2(Base):
    def __run2(self): # declares new __run2
        print("C2 run2")

o1 = C1()
o2 = C2()

o1.run()
o2.run()
```

This will result in:

```
C1 run1
```

Comment: gosh! now I will remember! thx!